# React Native pop up

Tags: react-native

I am modifying an app (Another developer made the source code) in react native. It will soon launch on appstore but I want to do one thing first.

I wonder if it is possible to create a pop up saying something like `"We are making updates, open the app again tomorrow"`. The pop up fills the screen and make it impossible for the user to use the app. I would then control this message from wordpress (which I use as backend).

How can I do this and is it even possible to create a pop up and control if its active or not without updating the entire app?

What I have found is this:[React Native Popup Dialog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-popup-dialog)

by using this code:

```
    import PopupDialog from 'react-native-popup-dialog';
import { Button } from 'react-native'

<View style={styles.container}>
  <Button
    title="Show Dialog"
    onPress={() => {
      this.popupDialog.show();
    }}
  />
  <PopupDialog
    ref={(popupDialog) => { this.popupDialog = popupDialog; }}
  >
    <View>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
  </PopupDialog>
</View>
```

The code above is triggered when pushing the button, but how can I control the view or hide status in real time from wordpress or some other way without the need of updating the app?